# Web-Crawler:phpmyadmin database connectivity

Tags: web-crawler

I created a simple web crawler and it is retriving all sites related to term specified. Now i want to connect it to my php search engine where it store all data in database with info and also show all data related to term. Can someone plz tell me how to do it. I did coding in php